# if one vertex is out of screen the entire triangle is culled out

Tags: irrlicht, culling

this is a noobish Irrlicht question because I just started working with it, but my problem is this: all the triangles of the mesh I'm rendering that have even one vertex out of screen, gets entirely culled out. this caused parts of the mesh that are partly out of the screen be completely invisible.

here's an image to illustrate the problem:

[image]

any ideas? (my camera is an FPS camera).

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok apparently this only happens in software rendering, with OpenGL it's ok.